# flatpak add additional dependencies after install (QGIS)

Tags: python-3.x, qgis, flatpak

I'm encountering a problem with the org.qgis.qgis package.  It has a self-contained python install which it uses to run its plugins and console.
[This page](https://qgis.org/en/site/forusers/alldownloads.html#flatpak) tells me to install python modules using the following command:
`flatpak run --command=pip3 org.qgis.qgis install pycurl --user`

But `pip install pycurl` fails due to missing dependencies (I recognized the error from when I'd installed the module onto the native python install of my machine).

I can (and already have) installed the dependencies natively so i am able to run the pycurl module from the natively installed python on my machine

From Flatpak's docs, I can see how a developer could add the build dependencies for the module to the flatpak dependencies.

But what If I am a user and I need to install additional dependencies not anticipated by the package maintainer?